# Using HtmlUnit, is there a way to pause execution of Javascript, then resume?

Tags: htmlunit

In HtmlUnit for testing, I'm coming across a case where, on page load, it'd be useful to NOT execute the Javascript automatically, and instead wait for me to initiate and tell the Javascript to start executing?

My specific use-case is testing something which the Javascript does some tests, and then does a location replace to send the user on to another page. I want to check some headers which I'm returning for testing/validation, and then let the JS execute as usual.

My current thought is to have a flag I pass to the page when testing which will cause the JS to not automatically run, and wait until I call a JS function from within the Java code via `webClient.getJavaScriptEngine().execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

While not specifically being able to pause JavaScript before invoking, it may be worthwhile to use the `WebConnectionWrapper` class to inspect/modify the response data or outgoing requests, effectively giving you a chance to execute your own code before the JavaScript is invoked.

An example usage of this is as follows:

```
 try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        // set more options

        // create a WebConnectionWrapper with an (subclassed) getResponse() impl
        new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {

            public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
                WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
                if (request.getUrl().toExternalForm().contains("my_url")) {
                    String content = response.getContentAsString();

                    // intercept and/or change content

                    WebResponseData data = new WebResponseData(content.getBytes(),
                            response.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusMessage(), response.getResponseHeaders());
                    response = new WebResponse(data, request, response.getLoadTime());
                }
                return response;
            }
        };

        // use the client as usual
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(uri);
    }
```

The above code is from the official documentation here:

[How to modify the outgoing request or incoming response?](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/faq.html#HowToModifyRequestOrResponse)

The getResponse() method that you would override is called before each request is made and also allows you to modify the WebResponse object that is passed back to WebClient for its continued processing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but at the moment (version 2.43.0) we have no such option. Feel free to open a issue on github for this.
I guess other test tools might also benefit from this function.